# Debugging a gradle-based Java project on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

My current project is composed of two modules, one android and another one that can be used as standalone desktop java. I'd like to run this second module by itself and be able to debug it without going through a device. I don't want to have a secondary IntelliJ installation to swap between one or the other.

Is there any way in AS to attach the debugger to a java gradle task?

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.project.Desktop.Launcher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "run this second library by itself?" Does it have a main method? What relation does this have to a Gradle task?

Comment: There is a core functionality library with tasks to build for android or desktop java. Android attaches the debugger automatically, java fails even when forcing OS level java console and debug. For reference it's a libgdx-based project.

Comment: You may only debug unit tests (Or any other executable -as in having a static void main method- that uses the library), you can't debug the library itself as a standalone project as Android Studio wouldn't know which routines to call

Comment: What if the library had its own entry point in a java-style application? I edited the OP to say it's more a module than a library. Picture it as 3 modules: one is common functionality which is platform-agnostic, which is a dependency of an Android launcher module and a Desktop launcher module. Unit test are platform-agnostic too but the launcher modules aren't.

Comment: In IntelliJ it's available on the click of a button, but AS is modified for android development so the option is either hidden or a bit more involved.

Comment: It might help if you posted some of your Gradle configuration. I'm still having a hard time understanding how the library module runs on its own. Does Gradle simply call some public method in the library for you?

Comment: This is the task: http://pastebin.com/iPF5A0d1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

> Then, you can run the application by running gradle run. Gradle will
>   take care of building the application classes, along with their
>   runtime dependencies, and starting the application with the correct
>   classpath. You can launch the application in debug mode with gradle
>   run --debug-jvm (see JavaExec.setDebug()).

Add to your build.gradle

```
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName = 'my.company.namespace.MainClass'
```

Create a new Run/Debug Gradle configuration

> 1. Run
> 2. Edit configurations
> 3. "+" (Add)
> 4. Gradle

or alternatively you can do a single [run] and duplicate the task.

> 5. For the task use `run --debug-jvm`
> 6. Rename it to [debug]

And from there attach the debugger following IntelliJ's indications:

> 1. Run
> 2. Edit configurations
> 3. "+" (Add)
> 4. Remote
> 5. Rename to "Attach debugger"
> 6. (Optional) On Before Launch, add Another Configuration and add [debug]

Now you can launch the [debug] followed by Attach Debugger, or if you followed Step 6 just press the Stop Debugger button once to get past the `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005 message` that can be considered as entry point.